# Populate Select2 with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

My function is:

`jQuery.post("example.php",{}, function(data){$("#select2").html('').select2({data: data});});`

and return json:
`{"results":[{"id":"aasd23423d3d","text":"dfasie"},{"id":"asdf2fsdf","text":"velder"}"}]}`

but select2 is filling in separating the letters from the words, like the picture

[Image Select2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBSaa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<select id="select2"></select>
```

```
$('#select2').select2({
  ajax: {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'example.php',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json'
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: data.results
      };
    }
  }
});
```

To know more, visit [Select2 with Ajax](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)

Comment: OP is making a post though. They may not need to be using a post but that's what is shown

Comment: @RashedRahat - good response.  Modest suggestion: add `type: 'POST'` to your example to satisfy charlietfl  (and make it easier for Mir Souza)

Comment: I've added @paulsm4

Comment: Welcone @MirSouza

Answer (score 1):

The last argument of jQuery.post is `dataType`. Try setting it to `'json'` and the data will get parsed internally to an object for you.

It appears that currently jQuery is assuming it is just text coming from server

If you are in control of the php code you also should set content type header for application/json

```
jQuery.post("example.php", 
   {}, 
   function(data) {
      $("#select2").html('').select2({
         data: data
      });
   },
   'json'
);
```